# Exception handling for missing parameters of a view passed on as json data

Tags: django

Lately, I found out the elementary truth related to exception handling - our server should rarely (preferably, never) through `5XX` error.
Having said that, let's consider a REST view with some parameters, and a respective URL.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^some_view/', some_view),
]

@api_view(['POST'])
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    param1 = request.data['param1']
```

In this code, I have to manually handle the exception where the developer calls `some_view` without assigning value to `param1`, otherwise - if I don't handle this case explicitly - they will get 500 error (`MultipleKeyValueError`) which is bad. And we have a dilemma:

- Handling it will cause irritating and repetitive try-except blocks, especially when we have multiple params
- Not handling will lead to 500 error

The solution is to rewrite the view this way:

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^some_view/(?P<param1>\w+/', some_view),
    ]

@api_view(['POST'])
def some_view(request, param1):
    # ...
```

Here Django will throw 400 exception - as opposed to 500 - saying that url is not found. But on the other hand, the first option (where I use `request.data['param1']`) gives the pleasant benefit that I can call the REST resource not only from an outside app, but also from my web app submitting params by serializing HTML form.

So here I am asking about the best practice. How do you, guys, handle this situation? Do you explicitly write try-except blocks watching for missing params, or do you use the url-parameters options, or maybe there's some third option that I didn't mention here ?

Answer (score 1):

> So here I am asking about the best practice. How do you, guys, handle
>   this situation? Do you explicitly write try-except blocks watching for 
>   missing params, or do you use the url-parameters options, or maybe >there's some third option that I didn't mention here ?

If I am trying to handle a common pattern for exception handling across views, I typically us a “third option” of writing a decorator that handles the exception and returns a JSON response with success = `False`:

```
from functools import wraps

def handle_missing_key(func)
    @wraps(func)
    def _decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except KeyError as ex:
            return JsonResponse({
                'success': False,
                'error': '%s' % ex
            })
    return _decorator
```

Then for your methods you can just do:

```
@handle_missing_key
@api_view(['POST'])
def some_view(request, param1):    
    pass
```

This way you're just sending back a 200 response but the JSON defines the error message and lets any calling application know what is missing.  You can find the missing key using `KeyError.args` or the error message in the `JsonResponse`.  If you want to send back a response other than a JsonResponse (i.e., status response 400 or the like), you can, of course, use something like this:

```
response = HttpResponse(status=400)
response.reason_phrase = 'Key %s is missing' % ex
return response
```

Comment: 2ps, I like this approach. A bit off-topic, but I wonder is there any way in Django to make this decorator a sort of "default"? That is, to make it active for all views without having to include it each time before a view ?

Comment: I’m not sure you could, or that it would be advisable since, presumably, you will have some non-JSON views in django as well (like the django admin interface).  If you only have JSON views, you could perhaps write some middleware that would handle it as a default.

Comment: This answer seems to be more about how to make Django return ok (200) instead of 400 exception. Or I am missing something?

Comment: I usually use this as a consistent way to handle exceptions of a particular type—in this case it can be used to handle `KeyError`.  But, just because I return 200, doesn’t mean you can’t return whatever status code you want to using `HttpResponse(status_code=400)` instead of a JsonResponse!

Comment: Ok. That was really useful think. Thanks for the answer. And yet, I can't tick it as answer, because it's though interesting, yet answer to other question)

Comment: Feel free to tick it or not as you deem fit.  But for clarity, here was your original question:  "So here I am asking about the best practice. How do you, guys, handle this situation? Do you explicitly write try-except blocks watching for missing params, or do you use the url-parameters options, or maybe there's some third option that I didn't mention here ? "  This was a proposed third option--a common decorator so that you don't have to write try-except blocks.  YMMV, and please don't tick if it wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing REST views, you should be using Django Rest Framework. One of the benefits of that framework is that you define serializers in which you declare which fields you accept and which are mandatory, just as you do with forms in vanilla Django. You can therefore return validation errors rather than 500s.

Comment: Daniel, this works for those cases when all the parameters are mapped to fields of some serializers. But what if I want to pass a parameter that is not associated with any model object (and therefore serializers). Say, it's a value to be used in an if-else branch in the view?